# AspNetCoreRateLimit .NET Core 3.0 - How rate limiting can be implemented based on user claim?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, rate-limiting

Is it possible to check rate limit after authentication has been done?

I would like to use one of the claims as client id and impose different rate limits depending on this claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried the solution yet but I figure out it could be possible with following approach.
Create you own `CustomRateLimitConfiguration` as pointed in the followind documentation.
https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/wiki/Resolve-Contributors

Out of the box the current version of `AspNetCoreRateLimit` (`4.0.1`) has support for only supports `ClientHeaderResolveContributor.cs` as resolver for ClientId rate limiting.

Hence you need to create custom resolver(`ClientClaimResolveContributor`) by inheriting from `IClientResolveContributor`, use the following code as reference from `AspNetCoreRateLimit` github repository.
https://github.com/stefanprodan/AspNetCoreRateLimit/blob/master/src/AspNetCoreRateLimit/Resolvers/ClientHeaderResolveContributor.cs

Read the authentication header using `HttpContext` and parse the jwt using following code.

```cs
var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(tokenstring);
var claim = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == "email").Value;
return claim;
```

The custom resolver class might look like this.

```cs
public class ClientAuthClaimResolveContributor : IClientResolveContributor
{
    private readonly string _cliamName;

    public ClientHeaderResolveContributor(string claimName)
    {
        _claimName = claimName;
    }

    public Task<string> ResolveClientAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string jwtToken = null;
        Claim claimToRead = null;
        if (httpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("Authorization", out var values))
        {
            jwtToken = values.First();
            var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ReadJwtToken(jwtToken);
            claimToRead = token.Claims.First(c => c.Type == claimName).Value;
        }    

        return Task.FromResult(claimToRead);
    }
}
```